# sonarqube : slow analysis : 30sec maven, 20 minutes of sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to work out why on a project of 1901 files, it takes 20 minutes to do the sonar analysis.
Yes, there are 93,000 violations (this is legacy code that is now being rewritten).

The problem is worse for some of my other projects, where sonar can take an hour to do the analysis.

Details are below, but the break down is this...

**2 minutes on JavaSource...**

```
[INFO] [11:41:39.452] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [11:43:26.651] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 107199 ms
```

**3 minutes...**

```
[INFO] [11:43:26.726] 1901 source files to be analyzed
<SNIP>
[INFO] [11:46:00.170] 1901/1901 source files analyzed
```

**2 minutes findbugs...**

```
[INFO] [11:46:58.851] Execute Findbugs 2.0.2...
[INFO] [11:47:00.764] Findbugs output report: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
[INFO] [11:48:17.666] Execute Findbugs 2.0.2 done: 78815 ms
```

**4 minutes on PMD...**

```
[INFO] [11:48:40.610] Execute PMD 4.3...
[INFO] [11:48:40.626] Java version: 1.6
[INFO] [11:48:40.658] PMD configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/sonar/pmd.xml
[INFO] [11:52:02.384] PMD configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/sonar/pmd-unit-tests.xml
[INFO] [11:52:02.385] Execute PMD 4.3 done: 201775 ms
```

**2 minutes for jacoco...**

```
[INFO] [11:52:12.710] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [11:52:12.716] Analysing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [11:54:31.749] No information about coverage per test.
[INFO] [11:54:31.749] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 139039 ms
```

**5 minutes for decorators and storing results...**

```
[INFO] [11:54:32.009] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [11:59:13.444] Store results in database
```

Is it just slow because the code has a lot of violations? What can I do to speed things up?

---

Sonarqube: Version 4.0 (Windows Server 2008 R2 - SP1: Intel 2Duo E6550 @2.33GHz, 6GB ram, 64bit)

Mysql : 5.6 (same box as sonar) New Empty DB : msqld.exe "Average CPU 7.14"

Jenkins: 1.540

Jenkins Sonar Plugin : 2.1

note: Sonar installed on x.x.72.215 : jenkins on x.x.72.175

JENKINS : "Analyzing with Maven" NOT "Analyzing with SonarQube Runner"

---

```
[INFO] [11:41:38.563] Initializer JacocoMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [11:41:38.563] Initializer JacocoMavenInitializer done: 0 ms
[INFO] [11:41:38.563] Index files
[INFO] [11:41:39.375] 1927 files indexed
[INFO] [11:41:39.376] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace
[INFO] [11:41:39.376] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/sonar
[INFO] [11:41:39.376] Source dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java
[INFO] [11:41:39.376] Test dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/test/java
[INFO] [11:41:39.376] Binary dirs: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/classes
[INFO] [11:41:39.376] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_GB
[INFO] [11:41:39.452] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [11:43:26.651] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 107199 ms
[INFO] [11:43:26.651] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [11:43:26.723] Java AST scan...
[INFO] [11:43:26.726] 1901 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] [11:43:36.726] 116/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/com/v21/dataDistribution/delivery/monitoring/PendingDeliveries.java
[INFO] [11:43:46.727] 271/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/base/BasicAppData.java
[INFO] [11:43:56.727] 402/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/common/SplashScreen.java
[INFO] [11:44:06.727] 536/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/devsim/NullDrawer.java
[INFO] [11:44:16.727] 672/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/engine/output/SoundInstruction.java
[INFO] [11:44:26.728] 778/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/error/ChangedException.java
[INFO] [11:44:36.728] 901/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/iface/Configuration.java
[INFO] [11:44:46.728] 1039/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/iface/IXmlWriter.java
[INFO] [11:44:56.728] 1158/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/herbert/HerbertScale.java
[INFO] [11:45:16.733] 1365/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/management/error/BasicException.java
[INFO] [11:45:26.734] 1498/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/data/IScratchTillUpdateLookup.java
[INFO] [11:45:36.740] 1625/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/system/util/StringArrayFormatter.java
[INFO] [11:45:46.740] 1742/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/tools/format/Graphics2DWrapper.java
[INFO] [11:45:56.740] 1859/1901 files analyzed, current is /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/src/main/java/uk/co/util/programs/FileEdit.java
[INFO] [11:46:00.170] 1901/1901 source files analyzed
[INFO] [11:46:00.392] Java AST scan done: 153669 ms
[INFO] [11:46:00.428] Java bytecode scan...
[WARN] [11:46:01.252] Class 'uk/co//system/engine2/DeferredProcessing' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [11:46:01.727] Class 'uk/co//system/engine2/DeferredProcessing' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARN] [11:46:02.008] Class 'uk/co//system/engine2/DeferredProcessing' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[INFO] [11:46:02.322] Java bytecode scan done: 1894 ms
[INFO] [11:46:02.555] Package design analysis...
[INFO] [11:46:17.788] Package design analysis done: 15233 ms
[INFO] [11:46:58.851] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 212200 ms
[INFO] [11:46:58.851] Sensor FindbugsSensor...
[INFO] [11:46:58.851] Execute Findbugs 2.0.2...
[INFO] [11:47:00.764] Findbugs output report: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/sonar/findbugs-result.xml
[INFO] [11:48:17.666] Execute Findbugs 2.0.2 done: 78815 ms
[INFO] [11:48:17.864] Sensor FindbugsSensor done: 79013 ms
[INFO] [11:48:17.864] Sensor SurefireSensor...
[INFO] [11:48:17.864] parsing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] [11:48:17.986] Sensor SurefireSensor done: 122 ms
[INFO] [11:48:17.986] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [11:48:17.986] SonarEngine is used
[INFO] [11:48:17.995] Cross-project analysis disabled
[INFO] [11:48:40.608] Sensor CpdSensor done: 22622 ms
[INFO] [11:48:40.608] Sensor PmdSensor...
[INFO] [11:48:40.610] Execute PMD 4.3...
[INFO] [11:48:40.626] Java version: 1.6
[INFO] [11:48:40.658] PMD configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/sonar/pmd.xml
[INFO] [11:52:02.384] PMD configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/sonar/pmd-unit-tests.xml
[INFO] [11:52:02.385] Execute PMD 4.3 done: 201775 ms
[INFO] [11:52:02.854] Sensor PmdSensor done: 202246 ms
[INFO] [11:52:02.854] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [11:52:09.920] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 7066 ms
[INFO] [11:52:09.920] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [11:52:10.981] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 1061 ms
[INFO] [11:52:10.981] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [11:52:11.025] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 44 ms
[INFO] [11:52:11.025] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [11:52:11.038] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 13 ms
[INFO] [11:52:11.038] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [11:52:11.094] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 56 ms
[INFO] [11:52:11.094] Sensor FileHashSensor...
[INFO] [11:52:11.114] Sensor FileHashSensor done: 20 ms
[INFO] [11:52:11.114] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [11:52:12.710] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 1596 ms
[INFO] [11:52:12.710] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [11:52:12.716] Analysing /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/inf/workspace/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [11:54:31.749] No information about coverage per test.
[INFO] [11:54:31.749] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 139039 ms
[INFO] [11:54:32.009] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [11:59:13.444] Store results in database
[INFO] [11:59:23.763] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://x.x.72.175:9000/dashboard/index/com.v21.infrastructure.legacy:v21inf
[INFO] [11:59:23.825] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[INFO] [11:59:24.110] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[INFO] [11:59:24.411] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[INFO] [11:59:24.428] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-10-25 and 2013-11-21
[INFO] [11:59:24.428] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2012-11-23 and 2013-10-25
[INFO] [11:59:24.428] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2008-11-28 and 2012-11-23
[INFO] [11:59:24.428] -> Delete data prior to: 2008-11-28
[INFO] [11:59:24.442] -> Clean V21 POS Infrastructure [id=5325]
[INFO] [11:59:24.447] <- Clean snapshot 40997
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I'm not surprised by the duration of the analysis for such a project (BTW, the number of files is not that important - the number of lines of code IS).

However, you can definitely speed up the analysis by tuning the quality profile. You probably have used "Sonar way with Findbugs". You could try with only "Sonar way" to start with.

Also, you can go and have a look at your project in the Web interface to see if there's a rule (or some rules) which specifically has lots of issues: if so, maybe the rule is not relevant in your case.

Comment: Sorry Fabrice, I've only just noticed your answer. Unfortunately its legacy code that we are refactoring and does have a LOT of issues. I turned down the number of rules to reduce the number of violations, and when we have removed 50% of the code, then I'll turn the rules back on for that project. BTW: the legacy code is 500,000 lines and 50,000 violations, so rather big.  I also moved the Sonar DB to a SSD.